# How would I add a dotted overlay to my background?

Tags: html, background

What I would like to do something like http://mountaintheme.com/themeforest/mountain/home.html and I'm not sure at all how to go about this. I've tried some methods utilizing CSS, but failed miserably.  This seems to be a simple fix I'd imagine...

This is my current code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sound Off</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">


<style>
    body {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        color: #000;
    }

    a {
        color: #fff;
    }

    a:hover {
        color: #fff;
    }

    hr {
        border-top-color: #fff;
    }

    .main {
        opacity: 0.6;
        max-width: 640px;
        margin: 150px auto;
        padding: 0px 15px;
        height:2048px;
    }

    .page-header {
        border-bottom: 3px #fff solid;
    }

    footer .accr {
        text-align: right;
    }

    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .clearfix div {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .rgb, .accr {
            text-align: center !important;
        }
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>


<div class="main">
<h1 class="page-header"></h1>
<p style="font-family:'Helvetica'"></p>
</div>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="colorScroll" data-colors="255, 255, 255:255, 255, 204:204, 255, 255">

var colors = $("#colorScroll").data("colors");
var colors_array = colors.split(":");
var numcolors = colors_array.length;

var RGBs = [];
for(var i = 0; i < numcolors; i++) {
    RGBs[i] = [];
    var c = colors_array[i].split(",");

    RGBs[i][0] = c[0];
    RGBs[i][1] = c[1];
    RGBs[i][2] = c[2];
}

var dRGBs = [];
for(var i = 0; i < (numcolors - 1); i++) {
    dRGBs[i] = [];

    dRGBs[i][0] = RGBs[i][0] - RGBs[i+1][0];
    dRGBs[i][1] = RGBs[i][1] - RGBs[i+1][1];
    dRGBs[i][2] = RGBs[i][2] - RGBs[i+1][2];
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var position = $(this).scrollTop();
    var view = $(this).height();
    var height = $(document).height();

    var travel = height - view;
    var percent = position / travel;
    var level = Math.floor(percent * (numcolors - 1));
    var plevel = percent * (numcolors - 1);

    var dlevel = Math.floor(level);
    if(Math.floor(level) == (numcolors - 1)) {
        dlevel = Math.floor(level) - 1;
    }

    if(plevel > 1) {
        plevel = plevel - dlevel;
    }

    var nRed = (RGBs[dlevel][0] - Math.round(dRGBs[dlevel][0] * plevel));
    var nGreen = (RGBs[dlevel][1] - Math.round(dRGBs[dlevel][1] * plevel));
    var nBlue = (RGBs[dlevel][2] - Math.round(dRGBs[dlevel][2] * plevel));

    $(".rgb span").text(nRed + ", " + nGreen + ", " + nBlue);
    $("body").css("background-color", "rgb(" + nRed + "," + nGreen + "," + nBlue + ")");

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Images having dotted effect http://mountaintheme.com/themeforest/mountain/demo/bg.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This is gif image you can download it through google crome.

You can download it from here. [Click Here](http://first%20go%20on%20to%20your%20link%20which%20you%20give%20Here%20in%20question.%20%20Now%20right%20click%20on%20screen%20and%20click%20on%20Inspect%20element.)

Comment: http://mountaintheme.com/themeforest/mountain/demo-2/images/spinner.gif copy and paste this in your browser and save image .

Comment: No its sends me to - http://first%20go%20on%20to%20your%20link%20which%20you%20give%20here%20in%20question.%20%20now%20right%20click%20on%20screen%20and%20click%20on%20inspect%20element.

Comment: i have add one more link try this "http://mountaintheme.com/themeforest/mountain/demo-2/images/spinner.gif"

Comment: ohh i didn't see this link - http://mountaintheme.com/themeforest/mountain/demo-2/images/spinner.gif yeah that one works :)

Answer (score 0):

It is jpeg picture as you can see from there page resources - http://mountaintheme.com/themeforest/mountain/demo/bg.jpg The Dotted effect was probably made with-in photoshop or something and then just saved.

Comment: right, im just curious if I can do such a thing without doing that. my background is quite dynamic so I cant commit to PS

Comment: You could add a dotted png and make it the size of the page